# Why does a UART message appear on sender XBee's input instead of output?

Tags: uart, digital-communications, xbee

I have a [XBee3 Mesh Kit (SMT)](https://www.digi.com/products/models/xk3-z8s-wzm) that comes with three [XBee3 SMT](https://www.digi.com/products/models/xb3-24z8us-j). I upgraded each Xbee3 SMT to the latest firmware (Zigbee-100D) in XCTU, and configured one module to be the coordinator and the other two routers. I don't always have an MCU or a UART sensor with me, so I thought of using one XBee router (**router-A**) to mimic the behavior of a real sensor - that is, to send the UART message through wire to another router (**router-B**). Router-B in turns sends the message wirelessly to the coordinator.

**Router-A:** I intentionally give the destination address DH/DL a nonexistent address (e.g. 1111 1111 1111 1111) so neither the coordinator or other routers can communicate with this module wirelessly. The UART pins are wired to Router-B.

**Router-B:** with the same configuration including default UART DIN/DOUT pin setups as Router-A except for DH/DL is 0/0 to address coordinator as destination.

I was supposed to connect **router-A (TX/DOUT)** pin to **router-B (RX/DIN)** but it wasn't working - I probed the message at A's TX/DOUT and the TX line was idle at all time.  But instead, the message appeared on A's RX/DIN. So I tried shorting the same RX/DIN on router-A and router-B (i.e. **A-RX/DIN to B-RX/DIN**) - it worked!!

Why didn't the connection **TX/DOUT-to-RX/DIN** work? Shorting two RX/DIN pins shouldn't be correct configuration.

[image: z1]

Comment: Is there a setting to reverse TX/RX? Quite a few devices have this in case the wiring gets backwards.

Comment: Some devices have TX/RX based on the view from the host (so you connect the host’s RX to the device’s RX), but the fact that you use RX on two identical devices is puzzling…

Comment: @DKNguyen, yep. The digital pins and specifically Rx/Tx is configurable in Digi's XCTU software. I left it as default and also double checked their values to be identical with both having DIO13=DOUT=Tx and DIO14=DIN=Rx. I got paranoid to the point that re-wrote the default values multiple times.

Comment: @jcaron it's indeed puzzling. Even if Tx/Rx is seen in perspective of the host it'll just reverse the sides and never can have two Rx shorted on both sides to enable a communication.  If I didn't get lazy and not use the extra XBee I had to emulate my source of UART in place of an MCU, I would not have encountered this issue. Not that it matters and there's hardly a practical reason to wire up two radios, but I still want to understand why this is happening.